# Buttons Appear Disabled in MvxListView Item Template with MvvmCross in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm working on an Android application using MvvmCross, and I'm facing an issue where buttons inside a MvxListView item template appear disabled (greyed out) and do not respond to clicks.

Here's the XML code for the layout containing the MvxListView:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/addButton"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/product_view"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FilterProduct; ItemClick ShowProductDetailsCommand"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the item template that contains the button:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff263238">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            local:MvxBind="Text NameProduct"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="+"
            local:MvxBind="Click AddProductCommand"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The buttons appear but are not active. They are greyed out and I have checked the viewmodel and everything is connected, I have checked but have not been able to give or understand why it is still like this.

I attach an image: https://i.ibb.co/PFhSLr0/e980c2f4-ebf4-4fd7-b1ae-fb1549c3ec48.jpg

Comment: Do you have a `CanExecute` portion for your `AddProductCommand`?